# what does Package has no installation candidate mean?

Tags: software-installation

i was trying to install wireless-tools in ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install wireless-tools
```

when i hit enter it shows like this

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Package wireless-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wireless-tools' has no installation candidate
```

help me to solve this problem

Comment: Post the `sudo apt update && apt search wireless-tools` result.

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @karel `wireless-tools` is available on main repository, it's not a ppa package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terminal run `software-properties-gtk` See if you have selected the options seen in the picture below.

[image]